# How to modify this regex so that it only matches directories and excludes files?

Tags: c#, regex

This is the regex pattern: **`^\D:(\\\w.+(\\?))+$`**

**〇 Ideal matches (expected):**
C:\folder1\folder2
C:\folder1\folder2\

**✖ But it also matches (actual):**
C:\folder1\folder2\file1.txt
C:\folder1\folder2\file2.docx

**Question** (so that it matches the OP title):
How should I change this regex so it includes files as mentioned in the above file examples?

OR

**Subquestion:**
Do you have any suggestions as an alternative to using Regex? Please refer below for details.
**Detailed scenario:**
In my WinForms app, I have a `TextBox` wherein its value is being loaded from a configuration file. Values can by anything - integers, strings, and even directories. If it looks like a directory (this is why I used regex), I want to validate this value by using `System.IO.Directory.Exist()`.

Comment: @metal No, `\D` doesn't mean drive D. It means 'not a digit'.

Comment: btw `file1.txt` as well as `file2.docx` are valid directory names

Comment: You could combine the results of `Directory.Exists(path);` and `File.Exists(path);`. In your scenario, if all exist, you'll have `true, false`, `true, false`, `false, true`, `false, true`.

Comment: A `"\D:\\\w.+\\"` match  will *confuse* a file without extension and a directory name. Or the other way around, if you try to *get the dot*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `file1.txt` as well as `file2.docx` are valid folder names, a better approach would be just to do a simple regex check:

```
(?i)^[A-Z]:\\
```

If input string matches this regex we consider that input string is a file system path and then you can try/catch `System.IO.Directory.Exist()` to actually check if 
provided path is an existing directory.

Comment: I see, even those are valid folder names. Thank you for this solution!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that maybe you are trying to write an expression somewhat similar to:

```
^\D:(\\\w+\\\w+(\\?))$
```

or maybe not, I'm not so sure.

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^\D:(\\\w+\\\w+(\\?))$";
        string input = @"C:\folder1\folder2
C:\folder1\folder2\
C:\folder1\folder2\file1.txt
C:\folder1\folder2\file2.docx

";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
> explained on the top right panel of
> [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7qEpLa/1/). If you'd like, you
> can also watch in [this
> link](https://regex101.com/r/7qEpLa/1/debugger), how it would match
> against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to match any level of directory with my regex, so what I did was something like this `(\\\w.+(\\?))+`. Btw, the test returned no matches, and did not enter the foreach loop. Thanks btw for jex.im and for mentioning the explanations in regex101!

Comment: `^\D:(\\\w+)*(\\?)$` is closer to what I initially wanted, although I accepted Kirill's answer due to the point that file-like strings are also valid folder names. That said still, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex:

`^\D:(\\\w+(\\?))+$`

It would take any kind of path without the files.

Example the Result:

```
Accepted > D:\Folder1\Folder2
Accepted > D:\Folder1\Folder2\
Not Accepted > D:\Folder1\Folder2\text.txt
Accepted > D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3
Accepted > D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\
```

and with more folder is also accepted like the example.

To include the files, just add `.*` like this:

`^\D:(\\\w+(\\?)).*` without any specific folder name, this one is not efficient because with only this `.*`, you also get the same result.

`^\D:(\\A\\).*` with first specific folder name and the whatever folder name and files.

`^\D:\\\w+\\\w+\\?\w+.\..*` with 2 folder is a must then follow by files.

Simulation [Here Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Bb7XBJ/5)

*Switch regex version to see other pattern or copy paste the regex to test.*